# What is the better netbook OS for me- Jolicloud or Kubuntu Netbook Edition?

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I've been considering either Jolicloud or KNE for my future netbook. It's going to be a dual core intel atom CPU and will have 512MB gfx, so resources shouldn't be a problem. One thing though: should I use Jolicloud OS or Kubuntu Netbook Edition? Note I will be dual booting Windows 7, which will be my 'working' OS. I will use Jolicloud/KNE for web browsing, 'tinkering' around, etc.

I want a 'complete' feeling from my netbook while not making it feel like a desktop/laptop. This will be my primary working computer (but, as I said, I'll use W7 for my work). What OS would you suggest I use? Jolicloud or Kubuntu Netbook Edition? I've trialed Jolicloud via Google Chrome, but it just doesn't feel right. KNE looks much nicer too; and it feels more complete. What should I use? Any personal experiences?

Comment: Answering to your question is likely be subjective, I don't think this is the proper place for Ubuntu vs others questions.

Comment: Jolicloud is an ubuntu derivative.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above by João Pinto any one that is answering is likely to be subjective.

So in my experience Jolicloud is just ready for netbooks. I have tested it and installed it for many friends and customers. What they love is, its clean purpose... the net. But jolicloud is not just the web, if you like vlc for viewing your videos you can install it through a very comprehensive package manager.

Note that jolycloud 1.1 is Ubuntu 10.04 under the hood and after they test their repositories it will automatically sync with 10.10 without bothering you. You can even check if your netbook is in this list 
http://www.jolicloud.com/product/compatibility
If it is, it is fully supported.... if not the check if Ubuntu 10.04 is compatible with it from : http://webapps.ubuntu.com/certification/

And last but not least, if you have tried Ubuntu 10.04 and it work then jolicloud will work.

Personally I loved Jolicloud...
You can test them both jolicloud and keep the one you loved most...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preferences either have an 'interface for netbooks' (like Jolicloud or upcoming Ubuntu 11.04 have). IMHO I would prefer to stay with traditional interface like Gnome or XFCE offer. So try to install standard Ubuntu (32bit) or lighter version Xubuntu.

I tried also LinuxMint on my relatively old netbook (Atom 1,6, RAM 512Mb, SSD 8Gb), but the final decision was for Xubuntu which is faster than Ubuntu with Gnome.

Best wishes,
Vincenzo

Answer (score 0):

Try the liveCDs and first and feel it from there, that way you will know which one you will use :)

Answer (score 0):

jolicloud is the best one 
I tested all the operating systems
jolicloud is even better (for now)then chromium os